# Jenkins Pipeline Get Parent

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins Scripted Pipeline and I need to get Parent Build Number.
How to do that?

I can get parent name by:

```
def parentDisplayName = currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent().getFullName()
println "Parent = " + parentDisplayName
```

How to get it's build number?

Comment: `getParent()` gets the `Job` that is belongs to, not a `Run`. `Job`s do not contain build numbers. A `Run` is an execution of a `Job`. There are methods to query about the next build number and such, but there is no specific build number associated with a `Job`

Comment: it did not work in Jenkins ver 2.41 Error: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getParent
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)`

Comment: so then how to you get the "run" of the parent job?